# show dynamic checkbox when its parentcheckbox clicked (ajax,jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter

i have two kinds of checkbox -> parent_checkbox and child_checkbox 
when parent_checkbox checked then it should show its child_chekbox.

when i check last parent_checkbox first-> then i get its child_chekbox. and then check other parent_checkbox i get its parent_checkbox respectively.

but the problem is when i check first parent_checkbox for the first time ->i get its respective child_chekbox. but again i click other(2,3,4) parent_checkbox i still get
child_chekbox of first  parent_checkbox and it for the rest of parent_checkbox getting same result.
HTML Part

```
<h5><p> parent</p></h5>
<?php foreach ($parentcheckbox as $parentcheckbox) { ?>
 <input type='checkbox' name='name2[]' value="<?php echo $parentcheckbox["id"]; ?>" class="parentcheckbox" class="form-control" >
<?php echo $parentcheckbox['name']; ?>
<?php } ?> 
<h5>child<h5>
 <div class="hidden show_childcheckbox" style="margin-top: 14px;">
</div>
</div>
```

and the script

```
<script>
$('.parentcheckbox').click(function () {
    var array = $("input[name2]").val();
    var childcheckbox_html = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/...",
        data: $('#tab4 :input').serializeArray(),
        success: function (response) {
            $(response.childcheckbox).each(function (i, v) {
                childcheckbox_html += "<input type='checkbox' name='name3[]' value='" + v.id + "' class='childcheckbox' class='form-control' >";
                childcheckbox_html += "label ='" + v.name + "' "
            });
            $('.show_childcheckbox').append(childcheckbox_html)

            $('.childcheckbox_html').show()
            console.log("44")
        }
    });
});
<script>
```

Comment: With jQuery problems, always show a sample of your output HTML (not just the PHP) as PHP is much harder to convert to an example JSFiddle etc. Use save-as from your browser.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie for the child_checkbox data is coming from database